# svn dump fails with WScript.Shell

Tags: svn, wsh, svn-administraton

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var commandLine = "svnadmin dump " + repoFullPath + " > " + repoName + ".dumpfile";
WshShell.Exec(commandLine)
```

I am trying to run above cscript in Windows but it seems like, it's doing nothing. It doesn't create the dump file.

Any mistake that I am doing?

Comment: How are you calling this script? Is this a hook script? What are the values of repoFullPath and repoName? How do these get valued?

Answer (score 1):

You have not assigned values to repoFullPath or repoName. Before the Exec line, put

```
WScript.Echo(commandLine);
```

so that you can see what the script is trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new command interpreter for your command using **cmd**, and have it terminate when done using the **/C** flag.

For example:

```
commandLine = "cmd /C svnadmin dump " + repoFullPath + " > " + repoName + ".dumpfile";
```